# regex - check that the string includes pattern only once

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to check that string includes specified pattern only once.
For example:

```
pattern = abc
qabce - returns true
qabceabcr - returns false
```

I tried to do this thing:

```
abc{1}
```

but it returns true if string contains a pattern at least once.

Answer (score 2):

You can check length of matched array and if it is `1` then it is a valid input;

```
function isValid(str) { return (str.match(/abc/g) || []).length; }
```

Then use it as:

```
isValid('foobar')
//=> 0 - Bad

isValid('qabce')
//=> 1 - Good

isValid('qabceabcr')
//=> 2 - Bad
```

---

If you want a pure regex solution then you can use this negative lookahead regex:

```
/\b((?!abc)\w)*abc(?!.*abc)\w*/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/50XxeL/5)

- `((?!abc)\w)*` is negative lookahead based match of 0 or more word char. It asserts that next position doesn't have `abc`
- `(?!.*abc)` is negative lookahead that asserts that we don't have another `abc` ahead in the word.

Comment: @user2417883: Did this work out?

Answer (score 2):

Try the global `g` flag

```
var multipleTimes = "qabceabcr".match(/abc/g).length > 1
```